# Add AJAX loader gif in prestashop

Tags: ajax, prestashop

I have two questions regarding prestashop.

1) How do I add an ajax loader image in prestashop for an ajax call?

2) Can I add an AJAX loader image to every ajax call in prestashop by placing some code in one place?

I am new to prestashop, so pardon my naive question if it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this script which will listen to all AJAX calls

```
//listen to ajax start event
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#my_loader').fadeIn();
});

//listen to ajax complete event
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#my_loader').fadeOut();
});
```

You loader html should be something like this

```
<img id="my_loader" src="..." />
```

Comment: I replaced ajaxComplete with ajaxStop: use case = on checkout page add a loading img for increasing-decreasing product quantities.